# The unit interval homeomorphic to the unit circle

Tags: general-topology

Is $[0,1]$ homeomorphic to $S^1=\{x^2+y^2=1:x,y \in \mathbb{R}\}$?

I've seen a function $g:[0,1) \rightarrow S^1$ defined by
$g(x)=(\cos 2x\pi,\sin 2x \pi)$, with the question, is $g$ is homeomorphism?

$g$ is clearly continuous, but I can not see weather it is a bijection and then has continuous inverse.

If the answer of the above question is No, I wont need to work with the above $g$ function. Thanks for any help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is a bijection but the inverse isn't continous. At $1 \in S^1$ you have the only discontinuity.

By the way. At first you say $[0,1]$, later $[0,1)$. Only the latter one makes the function injective.

Answer (score 1):

As @principal-ideal-domain explains, your map $g$ is not a homeomorphism. In fact there cannot be a homeomorphism (for both cases). If you are interested in the case $[0,1)$, then we can argue that $[0,1)$ is not compact while $S^1$ is. For the case $[0,1]$ we could for example say that if we remove a point from the interior of $[0,1]$ then the interval becomes disconnected but this doesn't happen when we do that to $S^1$ (this argument also works for $[0,1)$.